# Adding a table with ajax

Tags: javascript

i don't understand, why if i wanna export data from another site with ajax to table, i see each time above the data name of column and not one time.

```
async function ajaxRequest() {
     
    const response =  await fetch ("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const obj = await response.json()
    displayInformation (obj);
}

function displayInformation (obj) {
    const divResponse = document.getElementById("divResponse")
    let content = "<tr>"
    for (const user of obj) {
        const tr = `
        <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>${user.name}</td>
        <td>${user.username}</td>
        <td>${user.username}</td>
        <td>${user.phone}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            `;
          content += tr 
    }
    content += "</tr>"
    divResponse.innerHTML = content;
}
```

Comment: look at your code - you're adding the column headers in their own row *inside the loop*, so of course this will happen multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Place your row with table headers out of the for loop.

```js
async function ajaxRequest() {

    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const obj = await response.json()
    displayInformation(obj);
}

function displayInformation(obj) {
    const divResponse = document.getElementById("divResponse")
    let content = `<table><tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>`;
    for (const user of obj) {
        const tr = `
        <tr>
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.username}</td>
            <td>${user.username}</td>
            <td>${user.phone}</td>
        </tr>
                `;
        content += tr
    }
    content += "</table>"
    divResponse.innerHTML = content;
}

ajaxRequest();
```